# Почему через инклуд $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] выводит ip сервера?

Tags: php, .htaccess

В инклуде `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` выводит ip сервера, грешу на htaccess, так как настроил динамические поддомены. С поддомена захожу - такой баг. Напрямую всё нормально.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.test\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/show/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.ru/show.php?id=%1 [L,P]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так. Костыль, но всё же работает.

```
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ipaddress;
}
```